# Source control for use with VisualStudio + Xcode?

Tags: version-control

I don't know much about source control beyond what I have used at work [Perforce]. I'm looking for a product with the following..

- Free
- Centralized (server running on the LAN)
- Good integration with Microsoft Visual Studio (built-in / free plugin?)
- Good integration with Apple Xcode (built-in / free plugin?)

Are there many that fit those criteria? What would you choose?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode has built-in support for SVN, CVS and Perforce.

Visual Studio has a plug-in for most source code control systems. A free one for svn is [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

Answer (score 1):

SVN sounds like your only option.  I'd question why you think you need a centralised server, though.

Comment: The reason I said that is I like having only one place to make backups from and I will always have access to the server. If those are ill thought reasons then I'll happily consider others!

Comment: You don't need to use a centralised VCS in order to have centralised backups.  I'll bet you've got other things on your workstation that could do with a backup, though, anyway.

Comment: Whilst DVCS clearly has benefits one of the inherent advantages of old fashioned server based is that you de-facto have your code on two separate machines. There are benefits to a central repository that currently seem to be hard to recreate easily with a distributed system.

Comment: @Murph: *sigh*... you can trivially emulate centralisation if you want, either with scripts, or through some systems' built-in features (bzr bound branches, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Well subversion is the first one which comes in mind.

- Ankhsvn/visual svn for visual studio
- http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html for xcode